# JQuery script fails in IE 8! "Object doesn't support this property or method" -- compatibility issue?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

I have following html page with jquery script. 
Script is failing in IE8 at following line:

```
var dataCopy = JSONObject[event];
for (data in dataCopy)
```

error message I am getting is: "Object doesn't support this property or method". Same code works fine in Chrome and Firefox. Any suggestion would be great. I am trying to get all the distinct year values.

```
 !DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <title>
          Google Visualization API Sample
        </title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
        <script src="..\Scripts\jquery-1.7.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart', 'geochart', 'table'] });
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          function drawVisualization() {



            var JSONObject = {
                    cols: [{
                        id: 'Year', label: 'Year', type: 'string'
                    },{
                        id: 'data1', label: 'col2', type: 'number'
                    },{
                        id: 'data2', label: 'col3', type: 'number'
                    }],
                    rows: [{
                        c:[{v: '2000'}, {v: null}, {v: 3}]
                    },{
                        c:[{v: '2001'}, {v: 8}, {v:3 }]
                    },{
                        c:[{v: '2004'}, {v: 2.1244322}, {v: 4}]
                    }
                ]};

            var yearArray = [];

            for (var event in JSONObject) {
                var dataCopy = JSONObject[event];
                for (data in dataCopy) {
                    var mainData = dataCopy[data];
                    for (key in mainData) {
                        if (key.match(/c/)) {
                            var row = mainData[key];
                                yearArray.push(row[0].v);

                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            alert(yearArray.length);
}
</script>
```

Comment: `dataCopy` is not an object

Comment: `var JSONObject = ...` and `JSONObject` is not [JSON](http://json.org), it's a JavaScript object. JSON is a textual, non-source-code notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browsers other than IE8 support iterating over an array using the for...in iteration method. IE8 does not - it only supports iterating over objects in that manner.

I see you've got jQuery on your page so look at `$.each` - it will do what you want it to on both objects and arrays.

Comment: thank you! I have also tried using a simple for loop instead and it works too.

Comment: *"Browsers other than IE8 support iterating over an array using the for...in...IE8 does not..."* `for-in` does not loop through array entries. It loops through the enumerable properties of objects. It works on all standard JavaScript arrays (even in IE8 -- and 7, and 6) because [those aren't really arrays](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/myth-of-arrays.html), but may not work on host-provided arrays because they're not really JavaScript objects. `for-in` [shouldn't be used for this](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/11/myths-and-realities-of-forin.html) in any case.

Answer (score 0):

I created another array and used forloop to get around this problem.     Like Adam suggested I could have used $.each function as well.

```
var dataCopy = [];

        for (var event in JSONObject) {
            dataCopy = JSONObject[event];
            for (var k=0; k < dataCopy.length; k = k+1) {
                var mainData = dataCopy[k];
                for (key in mainData) {
                    if (key.match(/c/)) {
                        var row = mainData[key];
                            yearArray.push(row[0].v);

                    }
                }
            }
        }
```